# Abelian group of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove: If $G = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ is a finite abelian group, then $(a_1 a_2...a_n)^2 = e$, where $e$ is neutral in $G$.

I don't even now how to begin this.

Comment: Hint:  every element has an inverse distinct from itself unless it has order $1$ or $2$.

Comment: In the product $(a_1a_2...a_n)^2$, try to pair each element $a_i$ to its inverse.

Comment: @lulu Even simpler: Each element has a unique inverse, and no other element has the same inverse.

Comment: @Arthur  Ha!  good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $G$ is a group, every element $a_k$ has its inverse $a_k^{-1}$, which is one of the members of $G$, say $a_{k(n)}$ where $k:\{1,2,\cdots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ is a bijection (because every element has a unique inverse and the inverse of the inverse is the element itself), hence a permutation. Hence the set $\{a_1^{-1},a_2^{-1},\cdots,a_n^{-1}\}=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$. Therefore $$(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^2=(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)(a_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}\cdots a_n^{-1})=(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{-1}=e$$